# Git : How to coordinate work on multiple repositories

Tags: eclipse, git

Scenario: I'm mostly working with Eclipse to develop plugins. We have our repo that represents our development activities. Now I sometimes need to make some changes to a number of Eclipse or other 3rd party plugins, which are themselves hosted on Git. Then I need to have those modified plugin projects available as part of my codebase.

What I would like to do is to integrate all the remote repositories into a coherent local version where I can pull updates from those other read-only repos, but the changes that we make can be seen in our own repo, just like any other local working directory.

Comment: And you need these 3rd party plugins as src rather than jars that can be built and resolved via ivy/maven/gradle? IvyDE can resolve dependent projects in the workspace as well.

Comment: I need those as source since I need to tweak their code. Now I clone the plugin project git repo, import the project I want in my workspace and make necessary changes. After that I want to keep pulling updates and merging them in my local branch, but also push the changes to our main blessed repo.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use the git subtree command http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/

"The command to update the sub-project at a later date becomes:"

```
git fetch tpope-vim-surround master
git subtree pull --prefix .vim/bundle/tpope-vim-surround tpope-vim-surround master --squash
```

"When it’s time to contribute back to the upstream project we need to fork the project and add it as another remote:"

```
git subtree push --prefix=.vim/bundle/tpope-vim-surround/ durdn-vim-surround master
```

Comment: It sure sounds that git subtree along with sparse checkout is the way to go.